# Wget and Lynx not working, but apt-get working behind proxy

Tags: 12.04, command-line, apt, proxy

I have done:

```
export http_proxy="http://proxy.institute.edu:3128/"
export ftp_proxy="ftp://proxy.institute.edu:3128/"
export https_proxy="https://proxy.institute.edu:3128/"
export socks_proxy="socks://proxy.institute.edu:3128/"
```

I have done changes in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` directory for proxy. `apt-get` is working, but `lynx`, `wget` are not working. How to do using command-line. I have access only through `ssh`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can use `wget` with `--no-proxy` option. For example:

```
wget --no-proxy www.google.ro
```

And `lynx` with `PROTOCOL_proxy` option. For example:

```
lynx PROTOCOL_proxy www.google.ro
```

Comment: There also is a no_proxy environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Is not clear if your problem is that `wget` and `lynx` don't run behind a proxy while `apt-get` do, and Radu's answers throws me out the loop. But I will throw a stab in the dark:

From the export's I can guess that you are trying to set a proxy to work in the current session. Since Linux is Case Sensitive, if you set one but not both cases, you could run into problems:

```
env | grep -i http_proxy
http_proxy=http://localhost:3128/
HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:3128/
```

As you can see my environment uses both `http_proxy` and `HTTP_PROXY` so you must do the same:

```
export http_proxy="http://proxy.institute.edu:3128/"
export ftp_proxy="ftp://proxy.institute.edu:3128/"
export https_proxy="https://proxy.institute.edu:3128/"
export socks_proxy="socks://proxy.institute.edu:3128/"
export HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.institute.edu:3128/"
export FTP_PROXY="ftp://proxy.institute.edu:3128/"
export HTTPS_PROXY="https://proxy.institute.edu:3128/"
export SOCKS_PROXY="socks://proxy.institute.edu:3128/"
```

With this, we could be almost sure that if any program follow the environment variables will use the proxy. Now for the specific case of `wget` you can set the proxy manually in the `~/wgetrc` file:

```
http_proxy="http://proxy.institute.edu:3128/"
```

For `lynx` you should use `PROTOCOL_proxy` variable where the word *"PROTOCOL"* is replaced by lowercase http, ftp, https, etc... Lynx read the variables from your environment and if you have everything correctly set up you shall no have problems.

Comment: Actually I have set `http_proxy="http://proxy.institute.edu:3128/"`
`ftp_proxy="ftp://proxy.institute.edu:3128/"`
`https_proxy="https://proxy.institute.edu:3128/"`
`socks_proxy="socks://proxy.institute.edu:3128` both in upper and lower case inside the _/etc/environment_ file but still it is not working.

Comment: @parmeshwar89 did you ran `env | grep -i http_proxy` to check that they are actually set?